# Sound and video are slow

Tags: video, google-chrome, skype, youtube, slowmovideo

Whenever I opened google chrome today, everything seemed normal. I played one of my favorite games, and that's when stuff got weird. The sound on the game was slow. Not a major problem. I muted the sound. But then, I went to youtube on google chrome (everybody needs their daily Game Theories, right?) and when I went to watch a video, the video was slow AND the sound was slow. Okay, so I couldn't use youtube. But THEN, I opened Skype and tried talking. The sound was in slow-motion and it's messed up! (I wasn't actually talking to someone, I just used the Skype sound tester). I need help badly! I want to have normal video and normal sound D:

Answer (score 0):

It seems Google Chrome is not as good as it was only four months ago.

Not many months ago, perhaps August of last year, back when Firefox became hopelessly problematic, I became an outspoken advocate of using the Google Chrome browser.  Since then I've encountered unexplained total lockups of Google Chrome, and in later discussions discovered that both my girlfriend and another friend had been having the same experiences.

At the moment, my solution is to use a third, and much more difficult to install web browser known as Opera.  Since installing it, I've discovered that my home security system software works better with Opera than either Firefox or Chrome, so now I feel I need to have it on any computers I intend to use.  It is not uncommon to find me using two browsers concurrently, and sometimes three.

There are many tutorials on how to install it, some even on this site, and I've discovered that not all of them appear to work for me.  The one I continually return to is linked here.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser

I realize that one might say this isn't a direct answer to your question, I mean I can't tell you how to make the Chrome browser work properly, and I doubt anyone can.  I would advise you to try another browser for a while and return in a few more months to see if Chrome has been fixed yet.